# android exception NetworkOnMainThreadException (Already used asyncTask but still error)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am building a simple android app but I keep getting this exception NetworkOnMainThreadException. I have researched a lot about this, I understand that on android3.0(honeycomb) os and above, it is stricter, and should use asyncTask (on background thread), and I have done everything that I found, but still getting this exception, could someone guide on how to fix this ?

EditProductActivity.java :

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtPrice;
    EditText txtDesc;
    EditText txtCreatedAt;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;

    String pid;

    //progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //single product url
    private static final String url_product_details = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

    //url to update product
    private static final String url_update_product = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/update_product.php";

    //url to delete product
    private static final String url_delete_product = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/delete_product.php";

    //JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

        //save button
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        //getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        //getting product id(pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        //getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProductDetails().execute();

        //save button click event
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //starting background task to update product
                new SaveProductDetails().execute();
            }
        });

        //Delete button click event
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //deleting product in background thread
                new DeleteProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    //Background Async Task to Get Complete Product Details
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        //Before starting background thread show progress dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //getting product details in background thread
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        //Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        //getting product details by making HTTP request
                        //Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_details, "GET", params);

                        //check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        //json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            //successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); //JSON Array

                            //get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            //product with this pid found
                            //Edit text
                            txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                            txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                            //display product data in editText
                            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                            txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                            txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                        } else {
                            //product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            return null;
        }

        //After completing background task dismiss the progress dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    //Background Async Task to Save product details
    class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //Before starting background thread, show dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //Saving product
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            //getting updated data from EditTexts
            String name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

            //Building parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

            //sending modified data through http request
            //Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product, 
                "POST", params);

            //check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    //successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    //send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    //failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        //After completing background task, dismiss dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    //Background async task to delete product
    class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //Before starting, show progress dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //Deleting product
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            //check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                //Building parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                //getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_product, "POST", params);

                //check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete product", json.toString());

                //json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    //product successfully deleted
                    //notify previous activity by sending code 100
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    //send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        //After completing background task dismiss dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss dialog once finish
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

And for the layout xml:

edit_product.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <!-- Input Name -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <!-- Price Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <!-- Input Price -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputPrice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <!-- Description Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <!-- Input Description -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:lines="4"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- Button Update Product -->
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save Changes"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <!-- Button Delete Product -->
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the debug error stack :

> Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NetworkOnMainThreadException))
>     
>     DefaultRequestDirector.execute(HttpHost, HttpRequest, HttpContext) line: 531
>     DefaultHttpClient(AbstractHttpClient).execute(HttpHost, HttpRequest, HttpContext) line: 555 
>     DefaultHttpClient(AbstractHttpClient).execute(HttpUriRequest, HttpContext) line: 487
>     DefaultHttpClient(AbstractHttpClient).execute(HttpUriRequest) line: 465 
>     JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(String, String, List) line: 61
>     EditProductActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run() line: 120 
>     Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 733
>     Handler.dispatchMessage(Message) line: 95
>     Looper.loop() line: 136 
>     ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5017
>     Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
>     Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515
>     ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 779
>     ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 595 
>     NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

I think I have followed the rules in using asyncTask, doing the task on the background using onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(). I'm sorry I'm a newbie, any help is greatly appreciated.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think I have followed the rules in using asyncTask, doing the task
>   on the background using onPreExecute(), onPostExecute().

Not really because in your `doInBackground`you perform the HTTP request on the UI thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
```

which completely defeats the purpose of using an async task.

So remove the `runOnUiThread`, do your request in the background and when the task is completed use the `onPostExecute` to update your fields.

Comment: I'm so sorry for my rookie mistake, deleted it and it works like a charm, guess I should read more on the runOnUiThread and asyncTask. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

your doInBackground method is calling runOnUIThread, this is nonsense.

You should do your background work on doInBackground, and then execute the UI work in the onPostExecute, for example:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtPrice;
    EditText txtDesc;
    EditText txtCreatedAt;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;

    String pid;

    //progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //single product url
    private static final String url_product_details = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

    //url to update product
    private static final String url_update_product = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/update_product.php";

    //url to delete product
    private static final String url_delete_product = "http://api.kerjaapa.com/android_connect/delete_product.php";

    //JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

        //save button
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        //getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        //getting product id(pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        //getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProductDetails().execute();

        //save button click event
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //starting background task to update product
                new SaveProductDetails().execute();
            }
        });

        //Delete button click event
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //deleting product in background thread
                new DeleteProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    //Background Async Task to Get Complete Product Details
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
        //Before starting background thread show progress dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //getting product details in background thread
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    //Check for success tag
                    int success = 0;
                    try {
                        //Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        //getting product details by making HTTP request
                        //Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_details, "GET", params);

                        //check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        //json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            return success;
        }

        //After completing background task dismiss the progress dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
        if (success == 1) {
                    //successfully received product details
                    JSONArray productObj = json
                        .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); //JSON Array

                    //get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    //product with this pid found
                    //Edit text
                    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                    txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                    txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                    //display product data in editText
                    txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                    txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                    txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                } else {
                    //product with pid not found
                }
            //dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    //Background Async Task to Save product details
    class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //Before starting background thread, show dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //Saving product
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            //getting updated data from EditTexts
            String name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

            //Building parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

            //sending modified data through http request
            //Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product, 
                "POST", params);

            //check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    //successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    //send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    //failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        //After completing background task, dismiss dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    //Background async task to delete product
    class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //Before starting, show progress dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //Deleting product
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            //check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                //Building parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                //getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_product, "POST", params);

                //check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete product", json.toString());

                //json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    //product successfully deleted
                    //notify previous activity by sending code 100
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    //send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        //After completing background task dismiss dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss dialog once finish
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your doInBackground should run the network operation and post the result to onPostExecute, where you can update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

**doInBackground** does not interact with the main UI thread and you have mentioned Views in the **doinBackground** method of **AsynTask**

also remove **runOnUIThread** from **doInBackground**

also put these in **onPostExecute** method

```
 //product with this pid found
//Edit text
                            txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                            txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                            //display product data in editText
                            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                            txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                            txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
```